# Taking a input and multiplying each character by what is contained in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

Wasn't very sure how to properly word this feel free to tell me.

I'm sure there is a easier way but, If you could tell me how to do it this way, and give the other example that would be awesome!

I'm trying to extend the vowel of the users input by 5*

I basically have nothing but the list and the input typed out...
Put I still share the code that I have typed out so you guys can make fun of me.

```
vowels = ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y"]

long_vowel = str(input("Let's exaaaggeeeerateeee some vowels"))

# for vowels in long_vowel:
#     if vowels == long_vowel:
#         print(long_vowel)
# I know this does nothing was more of a structure for something more ^

print(long_vowel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a simple test case.

- what does "Hello world" return? when long_vowels equals "o"

Comment: It will print out two o's not on the same line tho